# Ubuntu 14.04 Start Terminal on Active Screen

Tags: 14.04, scripts, shortcut-keys, gnome-terminal

I'm currently working off Ubuntu 14.04 on **two separate screens**.

When I use the keyboard shortcut to start the terminal, Ctrl+Alt+T, the terminal is currently defaulted to open on the screen on the left, even if the screen I'm working on is the one on the left.

This issue applies to *gnome-terminal* only

I'm wondering *is there any way to set the terminal to launch in whichever screen is currently active*?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it in different workspace ?

Comment: Yes it works in other workspaces, but I have two screens in one workspace. I'd like to be able to open the terminal in the screen of the workspace that's active.

Comment: You can try seperate workspace for seperate monitors. This may help you : (http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/80774/separate-workspaces-on-each-monitor)

Comment: Hi @JacobVlijm, this StackExchange account is only available to me at work, and I was off Friday last. My apologies for missing your answer. Is there any way you could repost it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to make a new terminal window, initiated by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> open on the currently active screen?

Although *Very* much related to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/758003/how-to-open-a-file-in-the-same-display-i-am-working-it/758309#758309), not a dupe, and it requires a completely different solution. Your question is specific to `gnome-terminal`, and you are using a shortcut to start the application. These two make a background script unnecessary, and ask for some additional information.

#### The solution

Since you start the terminal by a shortcut key, it is relatively easy to create a clean soultion; we can simply replace the command, called by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>, to run a wrapper script. This wrapper will start a new instance, wait for the new window to appear, look at the current position of the mouse and move the new `gnome-terminal` - window to the corresponding screen.

#### The script

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import time

app = "gnome-terminal"

def get(cmd):
    return subprocess.check_output(cmd).decode("utf-8").strip()

def screen_limit():
    screendata = [s for s in get("xrandr").split() if s.count("+") == 2]
    if len(screendata) == 2:
        return int([s.split("x")[0] for s in screendata if "+0+0" in s][0])

rightside = screen_limit()
if rightside:
    ws1 = get(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]); t = 0
    subprocess.Popen(app)
    while t < 30:      
        ws2 = [w for w in get(["wmctrl", "-lpG"]).splitlines() if not w in ws1]
        if ws2:
            try:
                pid = get(["pgrep", "-f", app])
            except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
                pass
            else:
                match = [w for w in ws2 if pid in w]
                if match:
                    match = match[0].split()
                    mousepos = int(get(["xdotool", "getmouselocation"]).split()[0].split(":")[1])
                    check = [mousepos < rightside, int(match[3]) < rightside]
                    if check[0] != check[1]:
                        cmd = ["xdotool", "windowmove", match[0], str(int(match[3]) + rightside), match[4]] \
                              if check[0] == False else \
                              ["xdotool", "windowmove", match[0], str(int(match[3]) - rightside), match[4]]                       
                        subprocess.Popen(cmd)
                    break
        time.sleep(0.5); t += 1
else:
    subprocess.Popen(app)
```

#### How to use

1. The script needs both `wmctrl` and `xdotool`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
   ```
2. Copy the script above into an empty file, save it as `move_terminal.py`
3. Now we need to alter the default command, run by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

   - first disable the current shortcut by the command:

     ```
     gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys terminal ""
     ```

     This will make the shortcut available again.
   - Then Add a new command to Custom Shortcut Keys: choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

     ```
     python3 /path/to/move_terminal.py
     ```

     to the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>

Now your new `gnome-terminal` window, launched by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will always "follow" the currently active screen.

#### Note

If there is no second screen attached, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> will just open a new terminal window.

Comment: Many thanks @Jacob, your answer suits my needs perfectly. I'll go clean up the comments and accept this answer.

Comment: @AStanton Perfect! Glad it works.